# Do I qualify for a German visa? How do I apply?

Tags: visas, germany, covid-19

In the website of Germany Embassy in U.K., it is [stated](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/coronavirus?openAccordionId=item-2330824-3-panel) that

> [...]
>
> Urgent reasons for entry exist especially in the following cases.
>
> [...]
>
> **4. Educational reasons**
>
> initial entry: documentation from the apprenticeship or study
>   institution regarding the requirement of in person attendance as well
>   as proof of accommodation.
>
> [...]

Similarly, [the interior minister of Germany government](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html;jsessionid=263F35182123B235272FAD264A8CC5CD.2_cid364#doc13797140bodyText3) states that

> What are valid grounds for crossing the border?
>
> [...]
>
> Travellers can be permitted to cross borders to visit their partners
>   or families, receive medical treatment, attend educational and
>   training institutions that require in-person attendance, or attend
>   important family events.

My situation as follows, I will conduct internship starting from 15 of June, and I am starting to my Master's program on the 1st of September of this year, both in Germany.

However, I am a Turkish national, living in U.K. for the last 6 months.

Now, I have to get a visa in order to enter Germany, but neither the embassy haven't, nor visametric (the external source which handles the visas for German embassy) opened, yet.

To make sure that I understand everything correctly: **Am I allowed to get a German visa?**

If so, how do I supposed to get it since visametric is closed?

Comment: A visa is a privilege, not an entitlement. To answer your question as you have phrased it, no, you're not **entitled** to a visa. If your question is 'How can I apply for a German visa when the embassy is closed?' then you should edit it to say that. I don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Sorry, I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Many people must be in a similar situation. What is particularly ‘urgent’ about your case, and do you have the documentation from the relevant institution(s) regarding the requirement of in person attendance as well as proof of accommodation?

Comment: @Traveller My urgency is it is an important research internship for my education, and yes, I have all the necessary documents which state the need for my physical presence.

Comment: I have edited the title to more accurately track the content of your question. If you disagree with my changes, use the "edit" button below the question and you can revert the title back to what you originally wrote. And...you're doing just fine with your English.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not what you want to hear, but there is absolutely no chance that you will get the necessary paperwork done by June 15th.

You seem in general very little prepared and some of your alleged problems do not match publicly available information from the German Embassy in London. VisaMetric is completely irrelevant for your case. For your studies, you need a long-term national visa (type D) and/or a residence permit and applications therefore are handled directly by the embassy. VisaMetric is only handling applicatins for short-term visitor visas (type C).

Even if the embassy is closed for most purposes, they are still accepting and handling [applications for long-term visas under certain conditions](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa):

> Visa applications are currently not being accepted by the German Embassy in London and the Consulate General in Edinburgh Due to the entry restrictions on all non-essential travel from third countries to the Federal Republic of Germany to contain COVID-19, the German Embassy in London and the Consulate General in Edinburgh are currently not accepting any new visa applications. **An exception may be made if the applicant can demonstrate the existence of compelling reasons that justify entry under the current rules.**

AFAIK, this has been the case during the entire lockdown. Even though all unpostponable services have been suspended during the lockdown, there has been no complete closure of the embassy.

The German Embassy in London does not publish any processing times for long-term visas, but even without any corona restrictions, you should have planned at least several months. Had you applied for a visa mid March, before the lockdown, it would still not have been obvious that the application had been processed before June 15th.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; actually, this was planned around mid-march, but due to the virus, everything put on hold, so I didn't make any move related to that. Since the travel restrictions between Germany and UK will be lifted on the 15th, I was hoping to use that relaxation, even though I am not a UK national (but effectively, I have been living in here for the last 6months, so in terms of the risk related to the virus, there is no difference between me and a UK national)